# H265 videos stuttering on ubuntu 20.04 (Intel Nuc)

Tags: video, intel-nuc, mkv

I use an Intel Nuc and try to play h265 Videos via Kodi/Vlc but the videos are stuttering and sometimes the audio is out of sync.

Is there any way to get h265 mkv videos running smoothly on the Intel Nuc? (Without rendering the videos to h264 videos)

System: Kubuntu 20.04 with Backports
Intel NUC with Intel Atom Processor E3800/Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2820  @ 2.13GHz
4GB Ram

Comment: Besides: I didn't manage to get the mkvs running in vlc (there is only a black screen with no video but with the audio running)...

Comment: Hi, I see similar issues with a freshly installed 20.04.01 on a NUC7PJYH (CPU is a Pentium J5005, so I guess faster than yours) connected to a LG TV. VLC does not show just a static image for a .mkv file (1920x1080, H264), while sound is working. It sort of works with the default video player, but not very smooth. Youtube videos seem to work in the browser, and this NUC is supposedly fast enough, so I guess some driver issue. Did you understand your issue?

Comment: Yeah my Nuc seems to be too slow for h265 high quality mkvs....
I tried:
ffmpeg -i <video.mkv> -f null -
The value at the bottom (decoding speed) needs to be >1, to run mkvs smoothly. 
You could also try:
ffmpeg -init_hw_device vaapi=intel:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel vaapi
-hwaccel_device intel -benchmark -i <video.mkv> -f null -